# CakePHP 2 - Facebook integration

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Trying to add Facebook login / registration to a site I'm working on.
Been following this tutorial http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/34

After some tweaking (because I'm on CakePHP 2, while the tutorial is for 1.3), I managed to get it to run. (Basically I just need to pull the plugin from the branch)
Now, I'm having issues with 2 things:

1. How do I save the information? Right now, after I login, I just come back to the same page but instead of the Login button, it says "Teepusink is using ThisApp"
2. Also some of the documentation doesn't seem to match with the branch version. For example,

   Facebook->registration(); ?>

is giving me an error. Should I even be using the branch version? Or how do I go about using the plugin for CakePHP 2?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work actually.
So I went into ConnectComponent.php, and noticed that somehow the User model isn't being "recognized" there.
Took a little digging, but this is what I did.

```
'Facebook.Connect' => array('model' => 'User')
```

Hope this helps someone.